# Print Transparent Shapes

Tags: excel, vba, printing, transparency, shapes

I have a map of the warehouse where I work, and I'm trying to make a heatmap of activity that has taken place within a certain aisle.

I have managed to get the VBA working by having permanent red shapes positioned over each aisle, then adjusting the transparency of each box according to the percentage of the aisle.

It looks great on screen, however the multiple methods i have tried for printing does not work;

Expected output (this is what it looks like on screen):

[image]

The various methods I have tried all produce the same result, these include :-

- Printing directly
- SaveAs PDF
- Print as PDF (We have PDF virtual printer)
- Save Range as a Bitmap
- Copy Screen into a Chart, then save export the chart as image

Exported AS PDF :-

[image]

Saved as Bitmap :-

[image]

When it is printed it has different patterns within the red area, from what i have found, each pattern represents a certain transparency.

Short of using PRTSCN on my keyboard to get it and paste it into paint, i dont know how to move forward with this. This needs to be completely automated (ie, emailable and printable each day), so PRTSCR isnt really an option.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Most likely your renderer has limited color depth, so it tried to "create" nuances by dithering. Unless you write the code that you use to generate the docs as you mentioned, one cannot suggest what options might eliminate your problems. More information, more chances to win. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that manages to come across this, what i did in the end, was the get the % of 255 and to set the RGB color value of the shape.

Example psuedo-code below:

```
for each shp in Activesheet.Shapes
    newTrans = 255 * Sheet5.Range("P" & i).Value 'New transparency
    Shp.Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, newTrans, newTrans)
    DoEvents
next shp
```

This will give a shade of red, based on the percentage on sheet5.